# Duplicate object Firestore console

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I need to duplicate a few items in the Firebase Firestore console. I tried, but there seemed to be only two options: Delete the document and Delete all fields.

Is there a option to duplicate an object in the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no feature in the Firebase console to duplicate a Firestore document. If you think that'd be a useful feature for many user, you could [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.

For now the easiest way to duplicate a document's contents is probably to write a small Node.js script for it.

Comment: Do you have a simple solution to duplicate a document with a Node.js script? I am an iOS Developer and can't program in Java script.

Comment: Oh, in that case you can do the same in Swift/ObjC. I typically have a admin panel in my apps (or a separate admin app altogether) where this could fit quite well too.

Answer (score 19):

Here is how you can do it:

1. From `More in Google Cloud`, choose any of the options listed. This will take you to a Google Cloud Console for firestore.
2. Go to `Data` section in the left side panel and click on the Document actions (three dots showing after the document id in the panel).
3. There is the `Add similar document` which allows you to duplicate the document!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  To help save people time finding it...the "More in Google Cloud" referenced here is a drop down on the upper right of your Firestore Console.  Follow Basil's steps (above) from there, it works great.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why the still not bring this feature to Firebase

Comment: For those that just want a quick link: https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/databases/-default-/data/panel/

Answer (score 0):

I dont if it is useful but it worked for me,

i am using the Firebase Realtime Database,

while on the current node just export the json and create new node then paste the downloaded json data as the option of object.